# gradle project sync failed. basic functionality(e.g editing,debuggin) will not work properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import a project in android studio. After import when I try to sync it with Gradle it says `Gradle Sync Failed. basic Functionality (e.g editing, debugging) will not work properly`. Android Studio version is 1.5.1. Here is what build.gradle looks like for my module that I am trying to run:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        classpath "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.2.2"
        classpath "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1"
    }
}
```

When I try to update gradle version to 1.0.0. It says:

```
The Project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
```

When I try to update gradle version to 1.5.0 It says:

```
Error:Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.7. 
If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in     
/Users/dubai1/ct-android/FlipNewsAppProject/FlipNewsApp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.
```

But changing this also does not removes the `Gradle Sync failed error`. How can I sync and run properly?

Comment: add "" in 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'

Comment: Thanks,But When I change it to   classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0". It gives Error:Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 1.7. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl /gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.

Comment: Which I change but no effect...

Comment: then do one this replace all " " with ' '

Comment: Still the same..build.gradle has other entries too..is it anything to do with gradle build tools version? as my android studio is 1.5.1.